# VueJS : Listing items from the state of selected object from checkboxes is preventing the checkbox to be unchecked

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a search component where I list all my filter categories which doesn't get unchecked when listing checked items.

I am using vuex store in my component to manage state.I have this mutation which handles addition and removal of categories which is working perfectly fine.

*store.vue*

```js
updateSelectedCategories (state, data) {

      const value = data.checked;
      let childId = data.id;
       const parentId = data.parent;


      let count = 0;

      for(let prop in state.data.selectedCategories) {
        if(state.data.selectedCategories.hasOwnProperty(prop))
          ++count;
      }

      if (value) {
        // Check if SelectedCatIsEmpty
        if (count == 0) {
          state.data.selectedCategories[childId] = data;
        } else {
          if (state.data.selectedCategories[Object.keys(state.data.selectedCategories)[0]].parent !== parentId) {
            state.data.selectedCategories = {}


            state.data.selectedCategories[childId] = data;
          } else {
            state.data.selectedCategories[childId] = data;
          }
        }

      } else {
        delete state.data.selectedCategories[childId];
      }

    },
```

This is my state:

*store.vue*

```js
  state: {
    loading : false,
    filter: {
      categories: [],
      color: [],
      material: [],
      price: [],
    },
    products: [],
    data : {
      mainCategory: '',
      selectedCategories: {},
      colors: [],
      material: [],
      price: [],
      action: 'categoryProductSearch',
      nonce: window.sage.nonce,
    },
    selectedCatSet: new Set(),
  },
```

I am storing all of my selected Categories at. `state.data.selectedCategories`

This mutation is triggered by an action in my filter component

*filter.vue*

```js
    handleCategoryChange (event, parent) {
      let data
      if(event.target.checked) {

        data = {'id': event.target.id, 'parent': parent,  'name': event.target.name, 'type': 'category', 'checked': true};
      } else {
        data = {'id': event.target.id,  'parent': parent, 'name': event.target.name, 'type': 'category', 'checked': false};
      }
      this.updateSelectedCategories(data);
      this.getProducts()
    },
```

And this is my template for checkbox.
*filter.vue*

```html
<div class="checkbox" v-for="(child, index) in category.children" :key="index">
   <input type="checkbox" class="input-filter" :parent="category.id" :id="child.id" :name="child.name" @change="handleCategoryChange($event, category.id)"
                        :checked="child.id in selectedCategories"/>
   <label :for="child.id"><p v-text="child.name"></p></label>
</div>
```

---

The issue occurs when I want to add a list of selected categories in the filter component
.
*filter.vue*

```html
  <button :id="category.id" class="selected-filters" v-for="category in selectedCategories" :key="category.id">
    {{ category.name }}
  </button>
```

The items get listed but when I UNCHECK my checkbox, it doesn't get unchecked with no issues in my console.log.

**When I remove the list of selectedCategories everything starts to work fine.**

Adding image.

[image: Image For better understanding]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot I found that when I remove id from the filter tag code the unchecking start happening again.

So the code that changes is:

```html
  <button class="selected-filters" v-for="category in selectedCategories" :key="category.id">
    {{ category.name }}
  </button>
```

> I am not sure why did this fix the issue but this does fix it.